# Change default for max attribute on results for @Resource on domain classes for Grails 2.3.x

Tags: json, rest, grails, resources

I'm working on an app that serves domain classes as json results. 
Is there a way to change the default *max* for the results?

What I'm doing is `http://site/domain-class.json` and I'm only getting 10 results. I want to avoid creating all the links as `http://site/domain-class.json?max=999`

Is there a way to increase that default value to something different? I tried searching the source code without any luck. :(

Comment: max=-1 releases the limit

Comment: really? @DaneelS.Yaitskov i cannot test it on my environment now, but I will take your word! :D

Comment: Yeap. I discovered after trying special values. Though my grails version is 2.4.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not configurable using the @Resource annotation.

However, you can always generate your controller for your domain and modify the implementation of the list() method to have a different default maximum.

Here is [the controller](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-plugin-rest/src/main/groovy/grails/rest/RestfulController.groovy) which backs a domain which is marked with the @Resource interface annotation. As you can see the default maximum value is not driven by any configuration value.

Using `grails generate-controller` for your domain will allow you to change that value in the generated controller for your domain.

Comment: Are you sure about that? How is it possible? :(

Comment: I'm sure about it because I looked at the source code that generates the controller for the @Resource annotated domain class on GitHub (grails-core). Now, if you generate-controller for your domain class you can edit the list() action to have a different default max value.

Comment: It is terrible that you are not able to change that default value.

Comment: Well, the thought is @Resource isn't designed to be that flexible. It's designed to be a very quick way to get things working. In the case where you need more custom solutions you are to take things to the next step and generate and modify your controllers. Even beyond that is custom marshlling. It's a progressive way. Now, all of that said. If you want add support for customizing that, make the change and add a pull request on GitHub XD

Comment: I understand and I agree that there is some progression to take into consideration. But I like easy things done, what can i tell you? :) // THANKS for the help ;)

Comment: Even for a quick solution, this is a stupid design decision. The default controller should simply return all values.

Comment: i agree @kiview at least a bigger limit, to avoid overflow issues... :(