# nested RESTful resources

Tags: rest, grails

I'm using the support for REST introduced by Grails in 2.3. My app includes the following domain classes:

```
@Resource(formats=['json', 'xml'])
class Sensor {
    String name
    static hasMany = [metrics: Metric]
}

@Resource(formats=['json', 'xml'])
class Metric {

    String name
    String value

    static belongsTo = [sensor: Sensor]
}
```

And in `UrlMappings.groovy` I've defined the following nested RESTful URL mappings:

```
"/api/sensors"(resources: 'sensor') {
    "/metrics"(resources: "metric")
}
```

If I navigate to the URL `/api/sensors/1/metrics` I expect the response to show all `Metric` instances associated with the `Sensor` with ID 1, but in fact it returns all `Metric` instances (up to a limit of 10)

- Is there a URL that will return only `Metric` instances associated with a particular `Sensor` instance (without implementing my own controller)?
- Is there a way to override the default limit of 10 results (without adding a `max` parameter to the request)?

Comment: In regards to changing the limit when using Resource, the answer is no. There was a previous discussion about this already on here. The reasoning behind this design choice was that Resource was designed to be quick and easy, with generating and modifying the controllers as the next level of customization. My previous answer to this has pointers to the Grails source to demonstrate that Resource doesn't allow this customization.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22336804/change-default-for-max-attribute-on-results-for-resource-on-domain-classes-for/22337550#22337550

Comment: @JoshuaMoore thanks, do you know if it's possible to get the `Metric` instances for a single `Sensor` instance?

Comment: Never used them but according to the docs: http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/guide/single.html#restfulMappings which appears to be what you have.

Comment: Let know if there is a better way than the provided answer. :)

Comment: @dmahapatro I think extending `RestufulController` and overriding `queryForResource` might be slightly better http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/webServices.html#extendingRestfulController

Answer (score 6):

Looks like it isn't that simple. :) We can get a vivid picture if this command is run:

```
grails url-mapping-report
```

to see

```
Controller: metric
 |   GET    | /api/sensors/${sensorId}/metrics           | Action: index  |
 |   GET    | /api/sensors/${sensorId}/metrics/create    | Action: create |
 |   POST   | /api/sensors/${sensorId}/metrics           | Action: save   |
 |   GET    | /api/sensors/${sensorId}/metrics/${id}     | Action: show   |
 |   GET    | /api/sensors/${sensorId}/metrics/${id}/edit| Action: edit   |
 |   PUT    | /api/sensors/${sensorId}/metrics/${id}     | Action: update |
 |  DELETE  | /api/sensors/${sensorId}/metrics/${id}     | Action: delete |
```

So, we would at least need a `MetricController` inheriting `RestfulController` and override `index()` to do an additional check for `Metric` and return list based on `Sensor` as shown below:

```
class MetricController extends RestfulController<Metric> {
    static responseFormats = ['json', 'xml']

    MetricController() {
        super(Metric)
    }

    @Override
    def index() {
        def sensorId = params.sensorId
        respond Metric.where {
            sensor.id == sensorId
        }.list()
    }
}
```

Above changed would provide the expected result (including the restriction on paginated results) for `/api/sensors/1/metrics` when hit.

Comment: And this is the LEAST verbose way to do this? How is this not default functionality ._.