# Grails 2.3 - accessing REST functionality

Tags: rest, grails, grails-2.0

I have my domain classes defined as follows, have no code in my controllers

```
import grails.rest.*

@Resource(formats=['json', 'xml'])
class Product {
    String name
    static hasMany = [productPrices: ProductPrice]
}

import grails.rest.*
@Resource(formats=['json', 'xml'])
class ProductPrice {
    int price
    static belongsTo = [product:Product]
}
```

My UrlMappings is defined as

```
"/products"(resources:"product")
{
    "/productprices"(resources: "productprice")
}
```

I have also tried the following based on SO input - but it does not work

```
ProductPriceController extends RestfulController<ProductPrice> {
 static responseFormats = ['json', 'xml'] 
 ProductPriceController() 
 {
    super(ProductPrice) 
 }

 @Override def index() 
 { 
    def productId = params.productId
    respond ProductPrice.where { product.id == productId }.list() 
 } 
}
```

I can access my data using the urls  /MyApp/products and /MyApp/products/1.

However I cannot access my data at the second level e.g.  and /MyApp/products/1/ productprices – It gives me a 404. I am just trying to get my basic code skeleton to work.

I am referring primarily to the post [nested RESTful resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22675247/nested-restful-resources).

Note: I know that long term I need to probably implement custom controllers as described in this article [Grails get child domain objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19144246/grails-get-child-domain-objects?rq=1), but before that I can't seem to get this basic code to work.

Pointers appreciated.

Comment: The SO answer that is being referred here suggests to at least have a controller for the child domain. Refer it again.

Comment: I updated my SO question and manually added a controller, it still does not work. Thanks