# Expected default behavior for Grails RESTful mapping to Nested Resources

Tags: rest, grails, nested-resources

I have my Grails Domain classes annotated with `@Resource` with the uri specifications in `UrlMappings` where I declare the resource nesting. But even though according to https://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#restfulMappings it seems that just declaring this the right way, I should have the correct behavior that I wanted, which is that a URL pattern such as `/nesting/1/nested` will list the `nested` domain that belonged to the `nesting` domain with ID `1`, the observed behavior is that it just lists out all `nested` domain objects.

So for that, my workaround is to have a controller implemented that overrides the `listResources` to filter the `nested` domain by the `nesting` domain. But what's weird to me is why I even have to do that at all. The documentation said it defaults to the `index` action but said `index` action seems to just behave as if it's the index() of `nested` (without taking `nesting` into account).

My domain entities are `WeightSensor`:

```
@Resource(formats = ['json', 'xml'])
class WeightSensor extends Sensor<WeightData>
{
    Set<WeightData> data
    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

its superclass `Sensor`

```
@Resource(formats = ['json', 'xml'])
class Sensor<T extends SensorData>
{
  Set<T> data
  static hasMany = [data: SensorData]
  String name

  static constraints = {
    name unique: true
  }
}
```

and `WeightData`

```
class WeightData extends SensorData
{
    Float weight
    static constraints = {
        weight nullable: false
    }
}
```

and its superclass `SensorData`

```
class SensorData
{
  @BindingFormat('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S') // 2019-07-11 22:00:28.909
  Date timestamp

  static belongsTo = [sensor: Sensor]

  static constraints = {
    timestamp nullable: false
  }
}
```

In my `UrlMappings` I have the following:

```
    "/sensor/weight"(resources: 'weightSensor') {
      "/data"(resources: "weightData")
    }
```

My `WeightDataController` extends from a `SensorDataController`:

```
class WeightDataController extends SensorDataController<WeightSensor, WeightData>
{
  @SuppressWarnings("GroovyUnusedDeclaration")
  static responseFormats = ['json', 'xml']

  WeightDataController()
  {
    super(WeightData, WeightSensor, "weightSensorId")
  }
}
```

And SensorDataController in turn extends RestfulController, and overrides the `listAllResources` method as below.

```
import grails.rest.RestfulController

class SensorDataController<S extends Sensor, T extends SensorData> extends RestfulController<T>
{
  String idProperty
  Class<S> sensorType

  @SuppressWarnings("GroovyUnusedDeclaration")
  static responseFormats = ['json', 'xml']

  protected SensorDataController(Class<T> dataType, Class<S> sensorType, String idProperty)
  {
    super(dataType)
    this.idProperty = idProperty
    this.sensorType = sensorType
  }

  @Override
  protected List<T> listAllResources(Map params)
  {
    Long sensorId = params.get(idProperty) as Long
    if (sensorId)
    {
      resource.withCriteria() {
        eq 'sensor.id', sensorId
        maxResults params.max ?: 10
        firstResult params.offset ?: 0
      } as List<T>
    }
    else
    {
      super.listAllResources(params)
    }
  }
}
```

Note because in order for me to have my `WeightDataController` class be used, I needed to remove the `@Resource` on top of `WeightData` domain entity above, another nice little gem of wisdom I had to discover with trial and error.

I can probably blame this on the fact that the documentation for nested resources seems a bit open to interpretation. But when we see in the documentation a URL like GET books/${bookId}/authors, doesn't that look like it should return the list of Author objects that belongs to the Book instance IDed by bookId?

I know that I'm not alone as I did find this online of someone asking the same question I have - https://gist.github.com/mnellemann/7cfff1c721ef32f0be6c63574795f795 but no one answered them either. I also came across another SO post [nested RESTful resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22675247/nested-restful-resources) that was abandoned 5 years ago as well.

But 3 people having the same question and no one responding to our questions (I asked mine on the Grails Slack community) usefully because there is a work-around is not acceptable. At the risk of having my question taken down for a slew of different reasons, I question the usefulness of even having the grails nested resource URL mapping in the first place because I could have done everything manually myself without having to "declare" such a nesting in `UrlMappings`.

In closing, what I'm trying to find out is whether or not there's more "configuration" I need to do to get Grails nested Resources to behave in the way that I expected, which is how the documentation painted, correctly. Because just doing what was described doesn't get me that.